# cannot start jstatd due to permission error

Tags: java, jvm

I try to run jstatd jvm monitoring tool on linux machine

```
jboss@hostAddr:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin> uname -a
Linux hostAddr 2.6.16.60-0.34-smp #1 SMP Fri Jan 16 14:59:01 UTC 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with following command:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=~/jstatd.all.policy
```

jstatd.all.policy contents

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {

   permission java.security.AllPermission;

};
```

Unfortunately I get following output:

```
Could not create remote object
access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses write)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses write)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:725)
        at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:122)
```

For some reason jstatd runs successfully on windows with the same command and policy file.

Linux java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

Windows java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What is effective user ID is it running?

Comment: If you have the need to install it on several machines, you might want to take a look at this project containing RPM and deb packaging of jstatd: https://github.com/hgomez/devops-incubator.  I've used it.

Comment: For JDK9+: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032095/starting-jstatd-in-java-9/51032943#51032943

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Make sure that tools.jar file exists and the user running the jstatd command has permissions to read it.
2. Make sure that the URL in the `jstatd.all.policy` that points to the tools.jar is correct and declares the protocol (file in this case). For example, depending on where the `java.home` variable points to, you may need to remove the `../` part in the path just like this (I had to):

   ```
   grant codebase "file:${java.home}/lib/tools.jar" {
      permission java.security.AllPermission;
   };
   ```
3. Starting from Java 1.4 the policy file needs to be **encoded in UTF-8 without BOM**. The EOL (CRLF vs LF) shouldn't really matter. Please see "Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax" document from Oracle, under "Changes" section for more information (link not provided because I don't have enough reputation points to post more than 2 links, but I'm sure you'll be able to find that document).
4. Use an absolute path to the policy file when running the jstatd command, e.g.

   ```
   jstatd -p 12345 -J-Djava.security.policy=/absolute-path-to/jstatd.all.policy
   ```

   EDIT: The `-J` parameter may no longer be required or supported in Java 1.8 so this command would be instead:

   ```
   jstatd -p 12345 -Djava.security.policy=/absolute-path-to/jstatd.all.policy
   ```

   (thanks @lisak for pointing this out)
5. Finally, once you pass this point you may find other problems (I did) and these posts pointed me in the right direction: [Using VisualVM to monitor a remote JBoss instance](http://www.sifraser.com/blog/?p=103) and [Remote Profiling of JBoss using VisualVM](http://hillert.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/remote-profiling-of-jboss-using.html). Basically you may need to use the -p parameter to use a different port if 1099 is already in use and add some java options in the JBoss `run.conf` via `JAVA_OPTS` (assuming you are monitoring JBoss instance). All explained in more detail in the links provided.

EDIT:
- Pointed dead link [Using VisualVM to monitor a remote JBoss instance](http://siniatech.com/blog/?p=263) to another page with the same content.

Comment: In my case some how ${java.home} or ${JAVA_HOME} did not work. I had to specify the full absolute path of tools.jar.

Comment: I had to use absolute paths both in the policy file and in the shell command.

Comment: @lisak, sorry I put the -J that you removed back in the parameter `-J-Djava.security.policy=/absolute-path-to/jstatd.all.policy` because that is how is meant to be according to [jstatd documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html). Have you found an environment or jstatd version where that isn't the case?

Comment: Imho it is no longer supported in java 1.8, at least it didn't work for me and from what I remember it works without `-J` even on java 1.7 ...

Comment: I tried without `-J` in Java 1.7 on Windows 7 and it doesn't seem to work. I have successfully used the `-J` on Java 1.5 and 1.6 on Solaris 5.10. If it is no longer supported in Java 1.8, maybe we should just add a note, but keeping the `-J` as it might be required in other versions or platforms.

Comment: Everything worked when I added  `-J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my_server_ip`. So at the end it was `jstatd -p 12345 -Djava.security.policy=/absolute-path-to/jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my_server_ip`

Comment: "Using VisualVM to monitor a remote JBoss instance" appears to be a dead link.

Comment: jstatd.all.policy file needs to be created at ${JAVA_HOME}/bin dir. 
I had to specify absolute path for it. Now simply run '${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/absolute/path/to/jstatd.all.policy &'  
verify with 'netstat -nap | grep jstatd'

Comment: Step 4 made me double-check my path - I was getting `Could not create remote object
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")` simply because the path I had specified to my policy file was incorrect. Check yours!

Comment: @LightDye , Cannot connect to XXXXXXXX:8091 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXXXX:8091/jmxrmi I am getting this error, what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 69):

Just found following script to run `jstatd`. I managed to run `jstatd` with this script
https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/1375032

```
#!/bin/sh
policy=${HOME}/.jstatd.all.policy
[ -r ${policy} ] || cat >${policy} <<'POLICY'
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
POLICY

jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=${policy} &
```

Comment: @michael nesterenko , Cannot connect to XXXXXXXX:8091 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXXXX:8091/jmxrmi
I am getting this error, what might be wrong ?

Comment: Hi, Michael.  Your solution is working well for me - I only changed the path to the policy file to be a hard-coded path because of what I've read in some other posts.  I was wondering how I can stop jstatd when it is run in the background with the &.  I've tried ps -x to see if I see the process but I don't, even though it is running because Visual VM can connect to it.  Please let me know if you have any idea on how I can kill the process when I'm done with it.

Comment: D'oh!  I started the processes as root, so I needed to do "sudo su" in order for the process to appear in the list.

Answer (score 22):

#### Update

As noted by others, the tools.jar and rt.jar are [removed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B) since JDK 9, see [Starting jstatd in Java 9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032095/starting-jstatd-in-java-9/51032943)

---

For Java 8, here's the one liner using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) (though bashism):

```bash
jstatd -p 1099 -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};')
```

Wrapped:

> `jstatd -p 1099 -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};')`

With `jdk1.8.0_92`, the java launcher option prefix **`-J`** is still required.

#### Note:

The original problem is more likely due to the tilde `~`, in `~/jstatd.all.policy`, isn't expanded hence not understood by java, meanwhile either absolute path or using `${HOME}` instead should work.

Comment: Worth noting that the `lib` directory is located directly under the JDK root, so the path probably shouldn't have the `..`. I used `file:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar`.

Comment: That depended on whether JAVA_HOME points to a JDK or JRE installation. Nevertheless since JDK 9, the tools.jar had been removed, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Java 11, you need view this answer:[Starting jstatd in Java 9+ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032095/starting-jstatd-in-java-9/51032943)
policy file is like this:

```js
grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.jstatd" {    
   permission java.security.AllPermission;    
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and that what you should do:

1. Make sure that `javac` is in your $PATH
2. Specify full (absolute) path to the policy file when running jstatd
   `jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/path/to/jstatd.all.policy`

It helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifying your path wrong (i was)?

Try putting the policy in /tmp/jstatd.all.policy and then running:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/jstatd.all.policy
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need to put it in /tmp, just make sure the filename is correct. I accidentally named mine jstatd.policy.all which didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

@michael nesterenko 's answer is all right.

But if sometimes you can't connect the server even if you have get the Jstatd up, u may try to assign the 'rmi.server.hostname'

```
#!/bin/sh
policy=${HOME}/.jstatd.all.policy
[ -r ${policy} ] || cat >${policy} <<'POLICY'
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
POLICY

jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=${policy} -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.x.x &
```

the hostname shoule be assigned as the public ip if you want to connect via public network.

Answer (score 1):

I created new policy with following content:

> grant codebase "file:/usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar" { permission java.security.AllPermission; };

and then start jstatd with that policy with following command:

> jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/usr/java/jstatd.all.policy &

Comment: using hardcoded path to tools.jar works well rather than variable & relative path

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional point about previous answers that cost me some minor time to figure out.
When I used relative path in the policy file `${java.home}/lib/tools.jar` it actually pointed jstatd to **`JAVA_HOME/jre/`** directory and since I had jdk installed I had to use `${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar` instead to get to the right place.

**EDIT** I was running jstatd from within a docker container running ubuntu with jdk 8 (JAVA_HOME was set correctly).

Answer (score 0):

in addition to LightDye's answer, you can open required ports in your netfilter with this command :

```
for port in `netstat -nlp | grep jstatd | sed -r 's/^.*\:([0-9]{4,}).*$/\1/'`; do iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport $port -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment jstatd; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) instead of `jstatd` which automatically handles this problem: just run it using `mvn exec:java` inside ejstatd folder.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
    grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.jstatd" {    
       permission java.security.AllPermission;    
    };
    grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat" {    
       permission java.security.AllPermission;    
    };
```

Try adding the above to

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\lib\security{policyFile}"