# Unable to start jstatd.exe to monitor applications remotely?

Tags: jstat, jstatd

Great day to you all.

I want to use jstatd to monitor JVM, GC, Heap and some important metrics of some applications running in remote machines.

When I tried executing the command `jstatd.exe` from bin folder of the java path via commandline, I am getting the below error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin>jstatd.exe
Could not create remote object
access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses write)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses write)
            at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
    xt.java:374)
            at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
    549)
            at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
            at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:725)
            at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:122).
```

When we checked for this error in internet, we came to know that, we have to add some security file which is mentioned in the link 
[cannot start jstatd due to permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939883/can-not-start-jstatd-in-linux). But, still we are getting same error.

Could anyone able to help us on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Java Version by "java -version" using cmd
In my case my java version was 1.7 ,so it did n't work .If this is the issue , update your policy file with right version as below:

```
grant codebase "file:C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Now run jstatd like this one below

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>jstatd -p 1234 J-Djava.security.policy=D:
\jstatd.all.policy
```

Hope it will work!

N.B try to connect from visualVM your remote host with this port[1234] , otherwise it won't work.

**Edit:**

**For jdk 1.6**

policy file:

```
grant codebase "file:C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

jstatd command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>jstatd J-Djava.security.policy=D:/jstatd.
all.policy -p 1234
```

Comment: This is very outdated. `tools.jar` no longer exists in distributions like OpenJDK 11