# VisualVM jstatd remote connection

Tags: java

I am running a tomcat on a remote Linux server. I want to connect it with VisualVM from my laptop with following steps:

1. start jstatd with `jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/path/to/jstatd.all.policy`, refer to [cannot start jstatd due to permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930180/1086907)
2. start jvisualvm on my laptop
3. add remote host with IP, but no applications appears under the IP node. I can `telnet IP 1099` from my laptop.

How to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by steps from [Blog: Profiling remote JVM using VisualVM](https://nljug.org/nieuws/blog-profiling-remote-jvm-using-visualvm/)

> If VisualVM doesn’t list the remote jvm’s, here are some tips in getting it working:
>
> **Binding issues**: sometimes jstatd doesn’t bind to the correct ip address. You can force binding it to a specific ip using something like
> `-J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.1.1.123`

You can check other parameters from the blog above if you still have the issue.