# Starting jstatd in Java 9+

Tags: java, java-9, jstatd

In the past, I have started jstatd via a security policy file, as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930180/1294116

However, in Java 9+, they have removed the `tools.jar` file, which means that this solution no longer works. Does anyone know how to get around this? (Currently I am back to getting the error `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write") ...`)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Java 19 Update:** [Release Notes - `jstatd` No Longer Requires a SecurityManager (JDK-8272317)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/19-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8272317)

> `jstatd` no longer requires a Security Manager and policy file. Running with `-Djava.security.policy=` to set a policy has no effect.
>
> Internally to `jstatd`, an `ObjectInputFilter` is used to allow only essential classes to be deserialized over the RMI connection.

---

## Solution

The following policy file should work for you (at least under Java 11):

```
grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.jstatd" {    
   permission java.security.AllPermission;    
};

grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat" {    
   permission java.security.AllPermission;    
};
```

Thanks to [Sebastian S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014509/sebastian-s) for pointing out `jdk.internal.jvmstat` also needed to be granted the appropriate permission and for confirming the above works. Thanks to [Gili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14731/gili) for the latter as well.

As shown below, the `tools.jar` file was removed and everything in it was split up into modules. The `jstatd` tool now resides in the [`jdk.jstatd`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.jstatd/module-summary.html) module. I couldn't find documentation regarding how it was determined which tool(s) went into which module, though the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/index.html) does tell you after-the-fact. Just note that some modules contain the code for a single tool while other modules contain the code for multiple tools.

---

## Documentation

From the [Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/security/permissions-jdk1.html#GUID-7450CEFD-8EDC-495E-A7A3-6C2561FA4999) documentation:

> If you are using a modular runtime image (see the `jlink` tool), you can grant permissions to the application and library modules in the image by specifying a `jrt` URL as the `codeBase` value in a policy file. See [JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) for more information about `jrt` URLs.
>
> The following example grants permission to read the `foo` property to the module `com.greetings`:
>
> ```
> grant codeBase "jrt:/com.greetings" {
>    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "foo", "read";
> };
> ```

From [JEP 200: The Modular JDK](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/200):

> ***Design principles***
>
> The modular structure of the JDK implements the following principles:
>
> - Standard modules, whose specifications are governed by the JCP, have names starting with the string `"java."`.
> - All other modules are merely part of the JDK, and have names starting with the string `"jdk."`.
>
> *[...]*

From [JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220):

> #### Summary
>
> Restructure the JDK and JRE run-time images to accommodate modules and to improve performance, security, and maintainability. Define a new URI scheme for naming the modules, classes, and resources stored in a run-time image without revealing the internal structure or format of the image. Revise existing specifications as required to accommodate these changes.
>
> *[...]*
>
> ***Removed: rt.jar and tools.jar***
>
> The class and resource files previously stored in `lib/rt.jar`, `lib/tools.jar`, `lib/dt.jar`, and various other internal JAR files are now stored in a more efficient format in implementation-specific files in the `lib` directory. The format of these files is not specified and is subject to change without notice.
>
> The removal of `rt.jar` and similar files leads to three distinct problems:
>
> 1. *[...]*
> 2. The `java.security.CodeSource` API and security-policy files use URLs to name the locations of code bases that are to be granted specified permissions. Components of the run-time system that require specific permissions are currently identified in the `lib/security/java.policy` file via file URLs. The elliptic-curve cryptography provider, e.g., is identified as
>
>    > ```
>    > file:${java.home}/lib/ext/sunec.jar
>    > ```
>
>    which, obviously, has no meaning in a modular image.
> 3. *[...]*
>
> ***New URI scheme for naming stored modules, classes, and resources***
>
> To address the above three problems a new URL scheme, `jrt`, can be used to name the modules, classes, and resources stored in a run-time image without revealing the internal structure or format of the image.
>
> A `jrt` URL is a hierarchical URI, per RFC 3986, with the syntax
>
> ```
> jrt:/[$MODULE[/$PATH]]
> ```
>
> where `$MODULE` is an optional module name and `$PATH`, if present, is the path to a specific class or resource file within that module. The meaning of a `jrt` URL depends upon its structure:
>
> - *[...]*
> - `jrt:/$MODULE` refers to all of the class and resource files in the module `$MODULE`.
> - *[...]*
>
> These three forms of `jrt` URLs address the above problems as follows:
>
> 1. *[...]*
> 2. Security-policy files and other uses of the `CodeSource` API can use `jrt` URLs to name specific modules for the purpose of granting permissions. The elliptic-curve cryptography provider, e.g., can now be identified by the `jrt` URL
>
>    ```
>    jrt:/jdk.crypto.ec
>    ```
>
>    Other modules that are currently granted all permissions but do not actually require them can trivially be de-privileged, i.e., given precisely the permissions they require.
> 3. *[...]*

Both *JEP 200* and *JEP 220* were part of [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Comment: I just tested your solution on OpenJDK 11 and found out, that you need to grant AllPermissions to `jrt:/jdk.jstatd` and `jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat`. Then jstatd starts without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

I found one (questionable) solution to this:

```
grant {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```